# iframe src change is being removed/added on browser back/forward click on Firefox (Quantum)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

When I click on a button to add a source into an iFrame, and then click on the browser 'back' button, it removes the source from the iFrame, as if it was a native "undo" behavior.

Now, even though I also have an eventListener over `popstate` on my document, it doesn't get there first. Whenever i click the first time, removes the iframe src, then the second time it might trigger the `popstate`. Sometimes it doesn't even do that. This only happens in Firefox, though.

Chrome, does the opposite, let's say I opened a new tab, accessed my test file, click the button to add the src, then click back on the browser, it will take me to a blank tab. But of course trigger the `popstate` first.

How can I achieve the same behavior as in Chrome? Is it doable?

I don't know how the code will work on Stackoverflow, but if you want to try it out and test it out, I suggest doing a local `index.html` file.

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {

   window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
      console.log('pop state!');
    });
};



function addSource() {
  window.history.replaceState(null, null, document.URL);
  $('#iframe').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/Zg8-AbXqv4M');
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="addSource()">FRAME IT!</button>
<iframe id="iframe" src="" width="400" height="400" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: Instead of trying to rewrite history, why don't you use an URL hash? Something like `window.location.hash = videoID`. Every browser understands that and you could implement a hash listener to load the video from the URL hash.

Comment: hey thanks for replying. This is a specific case that i was needing to bind the back browser button to something else than the normal behavior. I added a video there just as an example, in my case is a site under the same domain. I want to avoid the iframe erase/undo. Is it possible?

Comment: Oh, I see... I'm afraid I don't know a solution for that. Sorry...